# sublime text3 jshint error "Incompatible values for 'undefined' and 'undefined' linting options." when using IIFE expression

Tags: sublimetext3, eslint, jshint, iife, sublimelinter

OS: macOS Sierra **10.12.5** .

Sublime Text: Build **3126** .

jshint **v2.9.5** .

eslint **v4.4.0** .

I have installed below packages for linting the js file

1. sublimeLinter-contrib-eslint
2. sublimeLinter-jshint

In my each .js file,  IIFE `(function(){` has been written on the top of the file BUT linter gives below error in gutter

> Incompatible values for "undefined" and "undefined" linting options.

I have both `.jshintrc` and `.eslintrc` file in my project root directory BUT I am a bit confused 
1. Which linter throw this error? and 
2. How to resolve/fix it?

-.jshintrc_

```
{
    "node": true,
    "esversion": 6,
    "globals" : {
        "moment": true,
        "saveAs": true
    }
}
```

*.eslintrc*

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "globals": {
      "angular": true,
      "module": true,
      "inject": true,
      "moment": true,
      "saveAs": true,
      "AWS": true,
      "require": false
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": [0,"tab"],
        "linebreak-style": [0, "unix"],
        "semi": [2, "always"]
    }
}
```

JS file

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module().controller(function () { //....code.... });
})();
```

I have tried the rules as per [eslint documentation](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/docs/rules/wrap-iife.md)

```
"rules": {
        "wrap-iife": [2, "outside"]
 }
```

tried all possible values but did not succeed.

Comment: You can toggle linters using the *SublimeLinter: Toggle Linter* command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution by using Debug mode for sublimeLinter.

there are mixing of 2 *.jshintrc* files. one is the default ( which can be viewed by (context menu  > JSHint > Set Linting Preferences ) and other is custom *.jshintrc* which located in my project root directory and also there are 2 property `esnext` and `esversion` written which I think is not valid. from this [refrence](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-JSHint/issues/126)

so first clear all comments from default *.jshintrc* (*/Users//Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/JSHint Gutter/.jshintrc*) and remove `esversion` property from custom *.jshintrc* file and everything is working fine now.